# Keep the emacs BROWSE file up to date while editing

Tags: emacs, file-browser

I'm trying to use a source browser for a c++ project without using a big IDE.
My current favorite text editor is emacs.
I found a solution that fit well to my needs which is the ebrowse (not intrusive, can very easily add sources of third part dependancy...).
My problem is that it does not stay up to date while I edit a file already ebrowsed.
eg if I add a method, it will not appear in the tree, and I didn't find a command to update it.
I tried to do a script that execute the ebrowse command line with an (global-auto-revert-mode t) t try to automatically keep the open BROWSE file updated, but it complain about editing externally modificated file.

There is a solution or should I quit to redo the BROWSE file each time then reload it ?

Thanks a lot

PS: I already saw ecb, it is a bit heavy from my point of view, and there is an annoying known bug that force me to trick by an ugly way [ecb permission denied bug](http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.code-browser/page=2) http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.code-browser/page=2

Comment: @MinkusCNB, I think this question fits well here.  Emacs and ebrowse certainly qualify as "software tools commonly used by programmers" as described in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @legoscia possibly.  Generally I think this question would be better answered in SuperUser.  It definitely did fall under C++, but I do see your point.  I retract my original objection though I do think my suggestion on checking out SuperUser(superuser.com) is still valid.